# How to overwrite .GlobalEnv with other environment

Tags: r

I have tried this:

```
myEnv <- new.env()
assign("X", 42, envir = myEnv)
.GlobalEnv <- myEnv
```

But nothing happens. Is there a way to do that?

The desired output is to have the variable `X` in the .GlobalEnv.

---

EDIT: Some people need some context...

I have scripts organized this way :

```
# ls R/*
1-import.R
2-data-management.R
3-imputation.R
4-table-1.R
...
```

I am designing a package that would keep a hidden dir with meta info and data:

```
# ls R/.hidden/*
1-import.R.Rdata
1-import.R.duration
2-data-management.R.Rdata
2-data-management.R.duration
...
```

I will create a `my_source()` function that source only scripts that has previous scripts modified. For this I have to handle a temp environment, source scripts in it and deliver the result in .GlobalEnv.

The 0.0.1 version of this package is here https://github.com/pietrodito/numbr

Comment: What exactly are you retrying to accomplish? I'm not sure I understand why you would want to replace your global environment. Do you just want to run code inside of a different environment? Or do you want to copy all the values from `myEnv` to your global environment? Or remove all values from the current global environment?

Comment: I have edited the question. I was hoping that the use of overwrite in the tittle was obvious.

Comment: The `myEnv` variable has to live somewhere. It's unclear where that would be in this case. I really think it would be better to tell us why you think you need to do this. There may be better, more idiomatic ways to accomplish what you are after in R.

Comment: If this is for use with `source()`, use the `local=` parameter of the source function. That allows you to specify a parameter where the code will be run. This gives you far more control than manipulating a users' global environment which may have nasty side effects depending on what else they are doing.

Comment: This is what I do but at the end I have to make results available in .GlobalEnv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** To copy all elements of an environment to the global environment convert that environment to a list using `as.list` and then copy the contents of that list to the global environment using `list2env`.  Whether  you really need to do this or not is not clear.  Could you not just leave the objects in that hidden environment?

```
list2env(as.list(myEnv), .GlobalEnv)
X
## [1] 42
```

**2)** I don't really recommend this but rather than modifying the global environment it is possible to place myEnv on the search path and then you can refer to its objects as long as they are not masked by objects of the same name in the global environment.

```
X <- 43
attach(myEnv)

X
## 43

get("X", "myEnv")
## 42

rm(X)
X
## 42
```

### Note

Note that to create a hidden environment in your package you can just put this into the source code of the package and not export it.

```
myEnv <- new.env()
```

For example, the lattice package creates a hidden environment called `.latticeEnv` in this source file: https://github.com/cran/lattice/blob/master/R/zzz.R

Comment: I have edited the question. I do not want remove all objects from the environment only to overwrite objects with the same name, which is what happens by default.

Comment: I have modified the answer based on the changes to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get what you have in mind but check if the following serves your purpose:

```
library(rlang)

myEnv <- env()
env_poke(myEnv, "X", 42)
env_bind(myEnv, X = zap()) # Here I use zap() to erase the previous value you can also
                           # overwrite it with another value. 

> myEnv$X
NULL
```

or you can use the following code if you want your environment to contain itself:

```
library(lobstr)
myEnv$self <- myEnv

> ref(myEnv)
o [1:0x2a4c3231e98] <env> 
\-self = [1:0x2a4c3231e98]  # This shows the memory address where your env was created.
```